# How to replace a string with linebreaks?

Tags: .net, vb.net

i want to know how to replace string like this

[image]

these code is not working

```
1. RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Replace("aa" & vbCrLf & "bb", "test")
2. RichTextBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(RichTextBox1.Text, "aa" & vbCrLf & "bb", "test", RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

Comment: It looks like you need to use `vbCrLf ` twice instead of once.

Comment: not working sir @PeterB

Comment: Could you share the code of your second attempt?

Comment: @DREAM - how should it look when the code works?

Comment: Are you sure there are no spaces between those aa and bb, just crlf? Inspect the text reported by RichTextBox1.Text

Comment: @HansKeﬆing `RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Replace("aa" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "bb", "test")`

Comment: @dbasnett just replace aa and bb to "test" sir

Comment: there is no spaces between them sir, i use this is code in form1 load `RichTextBox1.Text = "aa" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "bb"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working using `VbLf`:

```
str = str.Replace("aa" & VbLf & VbLf & "bb", "test")
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yUei65

PS I am no expert on when `vbLf` is needed vs `vbCrLf` - I don't know why it needs to be `vbLf` on the DotNetFiddle site (or any other environment). In general vbCrLf is more likely to be needed on Windows, and vbLf is more likely to be needed on Linux + probably also MacOS.

Comment: RichTextBox uses `\n` as line feed (`VbLf`) and replaces all `\r\n` with `\n`

Comment: In general, there is `Environment.NewLine` which I would expect to address runtime environment differences and be preferable to trying to guess which of LF, CR, and CRLF is the appropriate separator.